# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown CSS Colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown pill that turns pink on hover and stays pink when clicked.  However if you click it twice and then move the mouse away it turns grey.

It is the "recipient" link in the following example:

[Example and code](http://www.bootply.com/7knejiguxy)

Why is this? Is there some CSS I can use to overwrite this functionality? I'd rather the background went black again.

This is what I mean:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant' reproduce your issue with the double click but I can see a `gray` background with <kbd>Tab</kbd> Navigation. Add also the state for the `:focus`. Try this:

```
.nav-pills>li>a:hover, .nav-pills>li>a:focus {
    background-color: #FF6699;
}
```

#### [BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/R2zyUf2qbv)